# Can we use potassium hydroxide to decarboxylate potassium benzoate to benzene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I know the famous reaction:

[image: Soda lime reaction with Sodium Benzoate]

I was thinking of extension of this reaction to other salts of Benzoic Acids such as:
$$\ce{Potassium Benzoate + KOH ->[CaO,Δ] Benzene + K2CO3}$$
Is this reaction really carried out in Lab or there is not a favorable outcome/different product/unfeasible reaction such as in case of Kolbe's Reaction we obtain different products(basically isomers) for Na containing compound and for K containing compound.

Comment: Benzene is cheap and widely available, no-one needs to make benzene this way.

Comment: @Waylander Ok , if not for practical purposes , consider this question for theoretical interest.

Comment: It certain works for sodium salts so I don't see why it would not work for potassium salts  https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Carboxylic_Acids/Reactivity_of_Carboxylic_Acids/The_Decarboxylation_of_Carboxylic_Acids_and_Their_Salts

Comment: And since expense is no object, try RbOH and CsOH... but **not** FrOH. Benzene is enough of a health hazard.

Comment: CaCO3, not K2CO3.

Comment: @Poutnik actually it's wrong in the diagram (at that time I was short of time so I didn't browsed much) it will be K2CO3 only. Refer: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Carboxylic_Acids/Reactivity_of_Carboxylic_Acids/The_Decarboxylation_of_Carboxylic_Acids_and_Their_Salts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reaction is famously known as soda-lime decarboxylation because of its use of [sodalime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soda_lime) which is mixture of $\ce{CaO}$ (75%) and $\ce{NaOH}$ (3%). It also contains trace amount of $\ce{KOH}$ (0.1%). You can however alter the composition where $\ce{KOH}$ is in majority while $\ce{NaOH}$ is in trace and the reaction will work in similar manner since the chemistry is not altered.